# How to get an input from two different combo boxes?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have to write a Java code where I should get input from 2 different combo boxes. The input, that I will get, has to be display in a text field. I have written a part of my code but I can't get the input.

This is what I have written so far:

```
package main;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class ComboI extends JFrame implements ItemListener{
    JComboBox dita = new JComboBox();
    JComboBox ora = new JComboBox();
    JLabel dita1 = new JLabel("Zgjidhni diten:");
    JLabel ora1 = new JLabel("Zgjidhni oren");
    JTextArea pergjigje = new JTextArea(2, 10);
    public ComboI(){
        super("Orari mesimor IE102");
        setSize(600, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        Container content = getContentPane();
        FlowLayout lay = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT);
        content.setLayout(lay);
        content.add(dita);
        content.add(dita1);
        content.add(ora1);
        content.add(ora);
        content.add(pergjigje);
        setContentPane(content);

        dita.addItem("E Hene");
        dita.addItem("E Marte");
        dita.addItem("E Merkure");
        dita.addItem("E Enjte");
        dita.addItem("E Premte");
        dita.addItemListener(this);


        ora.addItem("08:30 - 09:25");
        ora.addItem("09:30 - 10:25");
        ora.addItem("10:30 - 11:25");
        ora.addItem("11:30 - 12:25");
        ora.addItem("12:30 - 13:25");
        ora.addItem("13:30 - 14:25");
        ora.addItemListener(this);

    }
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
        String choice1 = event.getItem().toString();
        String choice2 = event.getItem().toString();

        if (choice1.equals("E Marte") && choice2.equals("E Marte")){
            String a = "hi";
            pergjigje.setText(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String choice1 = event.getItem().toString();
String choice2 = event.getItem().toString();
```

You can only generate an event for one combo box at a time, so if you want the values from the combo boxes you need to access the combo box, not the event.

The code would be something like:

```
String choice1 = dita.getSelectedItem().toString();
String choice2 = ora.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. please can you help me with this other part of my code? it should set a text at a textArea. this text should be related with the input.                                                                                                            if (choice1.equals("E Marte") && choice2.equals("E Marte")){
    String a = "hi";
    pergjigje.setText(a);

Comment: One question per thread. You should be "accepting" an answer when it solves the initial question so people know the problem has been solved. Regarding your follow up question, it does not make sense. .choice1 and choice2 can never contain the same value since they represent values from different combo boxes.

Comment: in fact it was a mistake i just forgot to change it when i wrote the code it should be choice1.equals("E Marte") && choice2.equals("09:30-10:25")

Comment: i'm sorry but i'm new in this website and i don't now yet how it really works

Comment: and thnx very very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getSelectedItem()` method, with a cast to `String`. Or, you can use `getItemAt` with `getSelectedIndex` and a generic `JComboBox<String>` for your fields - this has the advantage of compile time type safety, and not needing a cast.

```
String sd = (String)dita.getSelectedItem();
String so = (String)ora.getSelectedItem();
```

or

```
String sd = dita.getItemAt(dita.getSelectedIndex());
String so = ora.getItemAt(ora.getSelectedIndex());
```

The other advantage of the second approach is that you can instead use `getSelectedIndex` to get a day of the week, or a time slot, from an array without having to parse text. For example:

```
// using java 8 for the java.time.DayOfWeek enum
DayOfWeek day = DayOfWeek.of(dita.getSelectedIndex());
// simply storing the hour of the time selection
int hour = ora.getSelectedIndex();
// using joda time for time without dates
//   with org.joda.time.LocalTime
LocalTime time = new LocalTime(ora.getSelectedIndex() + 7, 30);
```

**Detecting when the user hasn't made a selection**

You should also be aware that, for your code, even if the user has not yet selected an item it will return the first item in the combobox.  You may therefore want to add a "choose an item ..." string before any of the other entries. For example:

```
dita.addItem("Select a day ...");
dita.addItem("E Hene");
...
// inside the listener
if (dita.getSelectedIndex() == 1) { // no choice made yet }
```

Comment: i changed the part of getting input but my code doesn't work yet. can u please help me?